# Software Update wants to replace my grub file

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, dell, update-manager

I have a dual boot ubuntu 18/windows machine. It is an XPS machine setup using the [respin script](https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin/blob/master/xps-tweaks.sh) which includes grub customisations.

During a software update today I get this dialog:

```
Replace your changes in '/etc/grub.d/10_linux' with a later version of the configuration file?
```

The changes drop down is empty. It doesn't indicate what changes it wants to make.

The claimed grub version after the update but before a restart is:

```
grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02-2ubuntu8.18
```

I have chosen to keep my custom grub file. What changes was the software updater trying to make and will it lead to any problems now that I have refused the replacement?

Comment: Grub is now 2.04 in 19.10 and 20.04, not sure what they back ported if not updating. But, It looks like your script is just making a couple of changed to /etc/default/grub which you can easily manually do. You also can backup grub and compare to new install's grub to directly see difference, if you do not want to parse script.